# Why does PIL.resize() change colors?

Tags: python, image, numpy, resize, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize an image stored as NumPy array using `PIL`. But it seems to also normalize colours across channels, which I don't want.

If I print `min()`, `mean()`, `max()` of the original and altered image, I got the following:

```
0 139.3552607574856 255
0 92.91526075748563 235
0 62.96987110846718 207

0 116.63458655562165 255
0 162.5862423160817 255
0 189.97112433075552 255
```

So, the resulted image looks like the original paint in blue.

Here is the code I use for resizing:

```
def resize(img, shape):
    pil_img = np2pil(img)
    pil_img = pil_img.resize((shape[1], shape[0]))
    np_img = pil2np(pil_img)
    return np_img


def np2pil(img):
    return Image.fromarray((img * 255).astype('uint8'))


def pil2np(img):
    np_img = np.asarray(img)

    if np_img.max() <= 1:
        return (np_img * 255).astype(int)
    else:
        return np_img
```

Library versions:

```
numpy==1.19.0
Pillow==7.2.0
```

Comment: Also tried to change **resample** and **reducing_gap** parameters, but they show no effect here.

Answer (score 0):

From your outputs, I assume, that the original input image is already of type `np.uint8`!? If so, why do you multiply with `255` and type cast to `np.uint8` in `np2pil`? You create integer overflows en masse (that explains the color changes); the actual resizing has nothing to do with that issue!

If I correct `np2pil` accordingly

```py
def np2pil(img):
    return Image.fromarray(img)
```

everything works perfectly fine. For some image, I get the following "before" and "after" `min()`, `mean()`, `max()` values:

```
0 103.00595625 255
0 91.01710625 255
0 85.2306375 255

1 103.01525 249
0 91.029375 255
0 85.249525 255
```

Slight differences are expectable due to the interpolation involved during resizing.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
NumPy:       1.19.4
Pillow:      8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```